# is the below code not thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

What's wrong with this below code?.

```
private Map<Integer, Integer> aMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer>();    
Record rec = records.get(id);
  if (rec == null) {
      rec = new Record(id);
      records.put(id, rec);
  }
  return rec;
```

1. Is the above code not **Thread-safe**?. Why should i use `putIfAbsent` here in this case?.
2. Locking is applied only for updates. In case of of retrievals, it
   allows full concurrency. What does this statement mean?.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not thread safe.

1. If there was another thread, then in the time between `records.get` and `records.put` the other thread might have put the record as well.
2. Read only operations (i.e. ones that do not modify a structure) can be done by multiple threads at the same time. For example, 1000 threads can safely read the value of an `int`. However, those 1000 threads cannot update the value of the `int` without some sort of locking operation.

I know that this may sound like a very unlikely event, but remember that a 1 in a million event happens 1000 times per second at 1GHz.

---

This is thread safe:

```
private Map<Integer, Integer> aMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
// presumably aMap is a member and the code below is in a function
aMap.putIfAbsent(id, new Record(id))
Record rec = records.get(id);
return rec;
```

Note that this might create a `Record` and never use it.

Comment: Read only operations (i.e. ones that do not modify a structure) can be done by multiple threads at the same time. - Does this mean full concurrency?.

Comment: I haven't heard that term before, but it seems to me that yes.

Comment: one final question replacing the put with putIfAbsent() does it make thread safe?.

Comment: Yes, if you do it carefully. The docs for putIfAbsent say "the action is performed atomically". Atomic means that the action is performed as one chunk that cannot be split/interrupted by other threads. I'll edit the answer for how to make it atomic.

Comment: I saw the edit, we need to wrap this code in a function which i understood... but what is "presumably aMap is a member"

Comment: I'm just assuming that aMap is some variable that might be used outside of the record get function.

Comment: Since you marked it private I'm assuming it's a class member.

Comment: Consider what @yshavit says in his answer. It's the same idea but it cuts down on the number of Records created but not actually inserted (because one's already there).

Answer (score 3):

It could or could not be thread-safe, depending on how you want it to act.

By the end of the code, `aMap` will safely have a `Record` for `id`. However, it's possible that two threads will *both* create and put a `Record` in, such that there are two (or more, if more threads do it) `Records` in existence. That might be fine, and it might not be -- really depends on your application.

One of the dangers of thread-safety (for instance, if you use a normal `HashMap` without synchronization) is that threads can read partially-created or partially-updated objects across threads; in other words, things can go *really* haywire. This will *not* happen in your code, because `ConcurrentHashMap` will ensure memory is kept up-to-date between threads, and in that sense it is thread-safe.

One thing you can do is to use [`putIfAbsent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent%28K,%20V%29), which will atomically put a key-value pair into the map, but only if there's nothing at that key already:

```
if (rec == null) {
    records.putIfAbsent(id, new Record(id));
    rec = records.get(id);
}
```

In this approach, you might create a second `Record` object, but if so, it'll not get inserted and will immediately be available for garbage collection. By the end of the snippet:

- `records` will contain a `Record` for the given id
- only one `Record` will have ever been put into `records` for that id (whether put there by this thread or another)
- `rec` will point to that record

Comment: I think you meant `records.putIfAbsent(..` and not `records.put(..` in your code snippet